# How to compress data (object) in Rest service during sending responce in java

Tags: javascript, java, rest

my piece of code is

```
  @POST
  @Path("/getJSONCompareData")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Object getJSONCompareData(@FormParam("testRunNum") String TRun,@FormParam("rptName") String reportName) {

   if(debugLevel>2)
      Log.debugLog(className, "getJSONStatsData", "", "", "Methad called");
      Object obj=null;
      try {
      int testRunNum = Integer.parseInt(TRun);
      String rptName = reportName;
      JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
      String statsReportNameDir = Config.getWorkPath() + "/webapps/logs/TR" + testRunNum + "/reports/compareReports/" + rptName + "/compare.report";
                    obj=parser.parse(new FileReader(statsReportNameDir));
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
      Log.stackTraceLog(className, "getJSONStatsData", "", "", "Exception - ", e);
     }
          return obj;
   }
```

file size i am reading is approx 10MB

i want to compress data as it is taking 1 min over network

How i compress my Obj and handle in ajax call

Comment: I think you should add more details (as tags too) about the framework you use.

Comment: I am using jersey for implementation rest call and from my js file i am hitting request  /dashboardserver/web/ReportWebservice/getJSONCompareData

Comment: I am using jersey for implementation rest call and from my js file i am hitting request                                                                     /dashboardserver/web/ReportWebservice/getJSONCompareData   which call getJSONCompareData method here i am reading a file whose size is approx 10MB  send as repose to my js file. I want to compress jSon object and send over network in responce if rest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compress JSON response using GZIP configuration on server.

Modern browsers supports gzip compressed content also Servers like Apache, Tomcat, JBoss etc supports gzip compression too. 

Hence if gzip is enabled in server, it compress's data then sends to client.

you can refer article http://viralpatel.net/blogs/enable-gzip-compression-in-tomcat/

GZIP compression will increase performance not only for js,jsp files but also for http requests as data will be compressed

Comment: yes i can able to do it with GZIP for send response from jsp file working fine  ----- response.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
  OutputStream outStreamObj = response.getOutputStream();
  //ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(strJSONData.length());
  GZIPOutputStream gos = new GZIPOutputStream(outStreamObj);
  gos.write(jsonString.getBytes());
  gos.flush();
  gos.close();
  out.println(jsonString);                        but  i want to do it for responce for my rest call

Comment: for response you have to set ** compression="on" compressionMinSize="2048" compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,application/json" ** in your tomcat server, or the server you are using.

Comment: Thankx Rupesh i have to add any other keyword for rest call as throw exception responce and request type is not same

Answer (score 1):

For compress data in Rest Service you have add(create) an annotation 
I have create an annotation name ** @Compress ** and implemented code for that on my server

import com.cavisson.gui.server.webdashboard.services.interceptors.Compress;

here is my class for compression

```
package com.cavisson.gui.server.webdashboard.services.interceptors;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import javax.ws.rs.NameBinding;

    /**
     * @Compress annotation is the name binding annotation.
     */
    @NameBinding
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface Compress {}
```

now i have bind this interface with my class GZIPWriterInterceptor withuse at rum time

```
package com.cavisson.gui.server.webdashboard.services.interceptors;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.WriterInterceptor;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.WriterInterceptorContext;

/**
 * This class is used for compressing data sending from server.
 */
@Provider
@Compress
public class GZIPWriterInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor
{
  @Override
  public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context) throws IOException, WebApplicationException
  {
    try
    {
      MultivaluedMap<String,Object> headers = context.getHeaders();
      headers.add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");

      final OutputStream outputStream = context.getOutputStream();
      context.setOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(outputStream));
      context.proceed();
    }
    catch(IOException | WebApplicationException  e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

### Heading ##

Comment: add @Compress in your rest service